# The Layman Answer Alternative

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

More than half of us probably are not even qualified to ask a proper physics question let alone answer one. Would it be ok to add Layman answers or examples to harder answers?

Comment: Seems to be the inverse of [this question by annav from a few weeks ago](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/7304/).

Answer (score 11):

I won't give my opinion on this directly, but I would like to point out the site description from the [first line of the Tour page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour):

> Physics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for active researchers, academics and students of physics and astronomy.

So, I would read that to mean that answering questions for the layman (qualified in your post as people not qualified to answer nor ask a question) is not within the scope of the site. Likewise, lay-questions are not within the scope of the site. It is possible somebody could interpret "student" to mean anybody with a passing curiosity -- and the community is a bit mixed on that. We do have many questions and answers that are approachable and deal with basic, real-life curiosities. And there are some who feel that is good, and some who feel that it is bad.